# Introduction to Scripting - Python Trying to find Seasons

Tags: python-3.x

```py
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

    
if (input_month in 'March') and (20 < input_day <= 31):
    print ('Spring')
if (input_month in 'April') and (1 <= input_day <= 30): 
    print ('Spring')
if (input_month in 'May') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Spring')
if (input_month in 'June') and (1 <= input_day <= 20):
    print ('Spring')
    
if (input_month in 'June') and (20 < input_day <= 30):
    print ('Summer')
if (input_month in 'July') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Summer')
if (input_month in 'August') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Summer')
if (input_month in 'September') and (1 <= input_day < 21):
    print ('Summer')
    
if (input_month in 'September') and (21 <= input_day <= 30):
    print ('Autumn')
if (input_month in 'October') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Autumn')
if (input_month in 'November') and (1 <= input_day <= 30):
    print ('Autumn')
if (input_month in 'December') and (1 <= input_day < 21):
    print ('Autumn')  
    
if (input_month in 'December') and (21 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Winter')
if (input_month in 'January') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Winter')
if (input_month in 'February') and (1 <= input_day <= 29):
    print ('Winter')
if (input_month in 'March') and (1 <= input_day < 20):
    print ('Winter')
    
else: 
    print('Invalid')
```

For most months and day it works, but I am getting:
April 11  'Spring' (which is correct) but also getting 'Invalid' and not sure why I am getting both
June 21 'Summer' (which is correct) but also getting 'Invalid' and not sure why I am getting both
November 7 'Autumn' (which is correct) but also getting 'Invalid' and not sure why I am getting both

I just don't understand why this is... could someone please help me understand my errors.  Thank you

Comment: The else is only attached to your last if.

Comment: First of all, replace `in` with `==`.

Comment: Worth nothing, but `in` might be somewhat appropriate because it supports abbreviations, albeit not case sensitive. Maybe `startswith` is better.

Answer (score 1):

`else` is only attached to the last `if`-`elif` chain that precedes it. But since you didn't use `elif` the final `else` is only attached to the last `if` and will fire whenever the condition in that `if` is false regardless of the outcome of all other `if` conditions in your code.

There are many easier ways to do this rather than error-prone enumeration of each and every bound.

For example, you could use a dictionary keyed by month which returns a function that accepts `day` as its only argument and uses the value of `day` to compute the season:

```
seasons = {
    "January": lambda day: "Winter",
    "February": lambda day: "Winter",
    "March": lambda day: "Winter" if day < 21 else "Spring",
    "April": lambda day: "Spring",
    "May": lambda day: "Spring",
    "June": lambda day: "Spring" if day < 21 else "Summer",
    "July": lambda day: "Summer",
    "August": lambda day: "Summer",
    "September": lambda day: "Summer" if day < 22 else "Autumn",
    "October": lambda day: "Autumn",
    "November": lambda day: "Autumn",
    "December": lambda day: "Autumn" if day < 22 else "Winter",
}
```

Given this data structure, you can use it with `seasons["March"](20)`.

Since you need to validate, I'd make that a distinct step. You can keep another dictionary that maps month names to integers representing their end date or number of days. Validation is then a matter of ensuring the key exists and that the day is `>= 1` and `<= days_by_month[some_month]`. For example,

```py
def validate(month, day):
    days_by_month = {
        "January": 31,
        "February": 28, # FIXME handle leap years
        "March": 31,
        # ... etc ...
    }
    return month in days_by_month and 1 <= day <= days_by_month[month]

validate("January", 31) # => True
```

Since February fluctuates, you may want to add an extra condition that uses the year to determine whether it's a leap year.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful... I am just starting python but really enjoy it.  3 weeks in but this is something I never thought of

Answer (score 0):

Use `elif` instead of `if`. Like this:

```
a = 200
b = 33
if b > a:
  print("b is greater than a")
elif a == b:
  print("a and b are equal")
else:
  print("a is greater than b")
```

Answer (score -1):

The else statement at the end is only attached to the last if. You would want to use elif for the majority of the conditions:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

    
if (input_month in 'March') and (20 < input_day <= 31):
    print ('Spring')
elif (input_month in 'April') and (1 <= input_day <= 30): 
    print ('Spring')
elif (input_month in 'May') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Spring')
elif (input_month in 'June') and (1 <= input_day <= 20):
    print ('Spring')
    
elif (input_month in 'June') and (20 < input_day <= 30):
    print ('Summer')
elif (input_month in 'July') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Summer')
elif (input_month in 'August') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Summer')
elif (input_month in 'September') and (1 <= input_day < 21):
    print ('Summer')
    
elif (input_month in 'September') and (21 <= input_day <= 30):
    print ('Autumn')
elif (input_month in 'October') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Autumn')
elif (input_month in 'November') and (1 <= input_day <= 30):
    print ('Autumn')
elif (input_month in 'December') and (1 <= input_day < 21):
    print ('Autumn')  
    
elif (input_month in 'December') and (21 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Winter')
elif (input_month in 'January') and (1 <= input_day <= 31):
    print ('Winter')
elif (input_month in 'February') and (1 <= input_day <= 29):
    print ('Winter')
elif (input_month in 'March') and (1 <= input_day < 20):
    print ('Winter')
    
else: 
    print('Invalid')
```